# LYRConversationOptionsDistinctByParticipantsKey unresolved identifier after updating to LayerKit 0.22.0

Tags: cocoapods, swift3, layerkit

After updating from Layer 0.17 to 0.22, I'm getting this build error:
"Use of unresolved identifier 'LYRConversationOptionsDistinctByParticipantsKey'"

Code:

```
let currentConversation = try! appDelegate.layerClient.newConversation(withParticipants: participantSet, 
    options: [LYRConversationOptionsDistinctByParticipantsKey : 0])
```

(options on new line for readability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always pays to read the changelog!

> **0.22.0** Introduced the LYRConversationOptions object meant for configuring conversation instance upon initialization. It replaces the LYRConversationOptionsMetadataKey, LYRConversationOptionsDeliveryReceiptsEnabledKey and LYRConversationOptionsDistinctByParticipantsKey which was previously passed through the options argument with a dictionary.

```
LYRClient.newConversation(withParticipants: participantSet, 
   options: [LYRConversationOptionsDistinctByParticipantsKey : 0])
```

becomes

```
let options = LYRConversationOptions()
options.distintByParticipants = false
layerClient.newConversation(withParticipants: participantSet, 
    options: options)
```